# Optional closures in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I need a closure method executed on demand.

In Swift 3 I used to do something like this:

```
// Declare closure
var checksPerformed: ((Void) -> Void)? // Declaration

// Call when needed
checksPerformed?() 

//Only executes when checksPerformed is called
checksPerformed = { _ in 
    // do stuff here
}
```

In Swift 4 this is no longer the case.

[image]

And after fixing this warning nothing works as before.
What is the new way of doing this?

If I'm updating the declaration to: `var checksPerformed: (() -> ())?` I'm getting

[image]

Comment: Just update it as: `var checksPerformed: (() -> Void)?` or `var checksPerformed: (() -> ())?` either way is fine. I personally avoid using `Void` instead I just use `()` where appropriate.

Comment: var `checksPerformed: (() -> ())?` // Declaration

Comment: @oyalhi I updated the question

Comment: @oyalhi The consensus is to use `Void` for return values only.

Comment: Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45183961/6541007).

Comment: Yes you have to remove the _. See answers below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Distinguish between single-tuple and multiple-argument function types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md)

```
// Declare closure
var checksPerformed: (() -> ())? // Declaration

// Call when needed
checksPerformed?()

//Only executes when checksPerformed is called
checksPerformed = {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var checksPerformed: (()->(Void))?
```

If you do that everything should work as expected.

Dont use the _ in when assigning the closure:

```
//Only executes when checksPerformed is called
checksPerformed = { 
    // do stuff here
}

//Call when needed
checksPerformed?()
```

Comment: In the last paragraph I said I did. It didn't work. I'll update my original message to include the error. And I cannot do this: `` var checksPerformed: ()->(Void)?`` . The ``Class has no initializers`` is thrown

Comment: You have to do (()->(Void))? this declares it as an optional closure; sorry in my org answer the ? Was part of the question sentence.

Comment: Updated the answer to made it more clear

Comment: Your answer is the same as in the comments below my questions. And it still doesn't work (see my updated answer with a screenshot)

Comment: @kernelpanic Remove the `_ in`. There are no parameters. Do you know that `_` is a placeholder for a parameter? In your original code you actually had a closure with one parameter of type `Void`, not a closure without parameters.

Comment: I agree the _ should be removed in assigning the closure

Comment: Make sure you first assign the closure before calling it. In the code the order is wrong