# Empty closures in Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, closures, void, swift4

I have been migrating my project code to **Swift 4.0**.

I am facing an issue with closures. In the below code snippet:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{    
    var completionClosure: ((Void)->(Void))? //WARNING: When calling this function in Swift 4 or later, you must pass a '()' tuple; did you mean for the input type to be '()'?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.completionClosure = { //ERROR: Cannot assign value of type '() -> ()' to type '((Void) -> (Void))?'
            print("This is a closure.")
        }
    }
}
```

The above code worked perfectly in **Swift 3.2**. And in **Swift 4.0**, it is giving me these warnings and errors.

I understand there is no point in using `Void` if the closure doesn't contain any `input arguments and return type`, i.e the closure could have been written like:

```
var completionClosure: (()->())?
```

But still, why is it giving me the error? Isn't `Void` same as `No Value`?

Are there any changes introduced in the concept of closures since **Swift 4.0**?

Comment: This SO answer by @OOPer can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45184498/488506

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `Void` is just an empty tuple `()`.

I think this is due to [Remove implicit tuple splat behavior from function applications (SE-0029)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md)

Basically this change says that you can't pass tuples as parameters anymore. You used to be able to either pass parameters by inserting stuff in the `()` after the function name or pass a tuple representing the parameters

```
func foo(a: Int, b: Int) {}

let tuple = (a: 1, b: 2)
foo(tuple)
```

Now you can't.

If we were to transform `foo` to swift 4, it would look like this:

```
func foo(a; Int, b: Int) {}
func foo(_ x: (a: Int, b: Int)) {}
```

So `(Void) -> Void` represents a function taking a `Void` parameter. You used to be able to pass nothing because `Void` is just an empty tuple, which, after the "splat" becomes "no parameters".